# Increment x axis value by 10 instead of 1

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and I got my x axis which is incremented like that:
[image: my chart]

My axis is incremented by 1 like that:
1,2,3,4,5,...,200
but I would like an axis with the value:
10,20,30,40,50,...,2000
So I would like to increment the x axis by 10 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for **[pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.pointInterval)**, which not only set the value of the tick but also of the value.

Answer (score 1):

You havce to increase the default tick interval.

```
xAxis: {
  tickInterval: 10
},
```

Comment: that only change the distance betwen two ticks not the scale, I want that the point 1 , doesn't exist anymore because it's not 1 but 10, 2 = 20, 3 =30 ect...